# debug:decoding Unicode is not supported

Tags: python-2.7

My code can run,but when I debug,it can enter the Subroutine.And the error is:"decoding Unicode is not supported".

I use anaconda.When I open the untitled0.py,the encoding is UTF-8 at the bottom of the screen,but when I open the fhmm_exact.py,the encoding is UTF-8-GUESSED.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-f6910c2dfa77>", line 1, in <module>
    debugfile('/home/wenwu/untitled0.py', wdir='/home/wenwu')

  File "/home/wenwu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 702, in debugfile
    debugger.run("runfile(%r, args=%r, wdir=%r)" % (filename, args, wdir))

  File "/home/wenwu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 400, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/wenwu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/wenwu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 78, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/wenwu/untitled0.py", line 37, in <module>
    fhmm.disaggregate(test_elec.mains(),output,sample_period = 60)

  File "/home/wenwu/nilmtk/nilmtk/disaggregate/fhmm_exact.py", line 287, in disaggregate
    mains_data_location = '{}/elec/meter1'.format(building_path)

  File "/home/wenwu/nilmtk/nilmtk/disaggregate/fhmm_exact.py", line 287, in disaggregate
    mains_data_location = '{}/elec/meter1'.format(building_path)

  File "/home/wenwu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 49, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)

  File "/home/wenwu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 67, in dispatch_line
    self.user_line(frame)

  File "/home/wenwu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 158, in user_line
    self.interaction(frame, None)

  File "/home/wenwu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 488, in interaction
    self.notify_spyder(frame) #-----Spyder-specific-------------------------

  File "/home/wenwu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 432, in notify_spyder
    fname = unicode(fname, "utf-8")

TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```

The following is code.
untitled0.py*

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (13,6)
plt.style.use('ggplot')

from nilmtk import DataSet,TimeFrame,MeterGroup,HDFDataStore

train = DataSet('/home/wenwu/redd.h5')
test = DataSet('/home/wenwu/redd.h5')

building = 1
train.set_window(end = '30-4-2011')
test.set_window(start = '30-4-2011')

train_elec = train.buildings[1].elec
test_elec = test.buildings[1].elec
fridge_meter = train_elec['fridge']
fridge_df = fridge_meter.load().next()
fridge_df.head()
mains = train_elec.mains()
mains_df = mains.load().next()
top_5_train_elec = train_elec.submeters().select_top_k(k = 5)

from nilmtk.disaggregate import fhmm_exact
from nilmtk.metrics import f1_score
fhmm = fhmm_exact.FHMM()
fhmm.train(top_5_train_elec,sample_period = 60)
disag_filename = '/home/wenwu/redd-disag-fhmm.h5'
output = HDFDataStore(disag_filename,'w')
fhmm.disaggregate(test_elec.mains(),output,sample_period = 60)
output.close()
disag_fhmm = DataSet(disag_filename)
disag_fhmm_elec = disag_fhmm.buildings[building].elec
f1_fhmm = f1_score(disag_fhmm_elec,test_elec)
f1_fhmm.plot(kind = 'barh')
```

disaggreate part of fhmm_exact.py

```
def disaggregate(self, mains, output_datastore, **load_kwargs):
        '''Disaggregate mains according to the model learnt previously.

        Parameters
        ----------
        mains : nilmtk.ElecMeter or nilmtk.MeterGroup
        output_datastore : instance of nilmtk.DataStore subclass
            For storing power predictions from disaggregation algorithm.
        output_name : string, optional
            The `name` to use in the metadata for the `output_datastore`.
            e.g. some sort of name for this experiment.  Defaults to
            "NILMTK_FHMM_<date>"
        resample_seconds : number, optional
            The desired sample period in seconds.
        **load_kwargs : key word arguments
            Passed to `mains.power_series(**kwargs)`
        '''
        import warnings
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=Warning)
        MIN_CHUNK_LENGTH = 100
        if not self.model:
            raise RuntimeError(
                "The model needs to be instantiated before"
                " calling `disaggregate`.  For example, the"
                " model can be instantiated by running `train`.")

        # Extract optional parameters from load_kwargs
        date_now = datetime.now().isoformat().split('.')[0]
        output_name = load_kwargs.pop('output_name', 'NILMTK_FHMM_' + date_now)
        resample_seconds = load_kwargs.pop('resample_seconds', 60)

        resample_rule = '{:d}S'.format(resample_seconds)
        timeframes = []
        building_path = '/building{}'.format(mains.building())
        mains_data_location = '{}/elec/meter1'.format(building_path)
        data_is_available = False

        for chunk in mains.power_series(**load_kwargs):
            # Check that chunk is sensible size before resampling
            if len(chunk) < MIN_CHUNK_LENGTH:
                continue

            # Record metadata
            timeframes.append(chunk.timeframe)
            measurement = chunk.name
            chunk = chunk.resample(rule=resample_rule)
            # Check chunk size *again* after resampling
            if len(chunk) < MIN_CHUNK_LENGTH:
                continue

            # Start disaggregation
            predictions = self.disaggregate_chunk(chunk)

            for meter in predictions.columns:
                data_is_available = True
                meter_instance = meter.instance()
                cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([chunk.name])

                predicted_power = predictions[[meter]]
                output_df = pd.DataFrame(predicted_power)
                output_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([chunk.name])
                output_datastore.append('{}/elec/meter{}'
                                        .format(building_path, meter_instance),
                                        output_df)

            # Copy mains data to disag output
            output_datastore.append(key=mains_data_location,
                                    value=pd.DataFrame(chunk, columns=cols))

        if not data_is_available:
            return

        ##################################
        # Add metadata to output_datastore

        # TODO: `preprocessing_applied` for all meters
        # TODO: split this metadata code into a separate function
        # TODO: submeter measurement should probably be the mains
        #       measurement we used to train on, not the mains measurement.

        # DataSet and MeterDevice metadata:
        meter_devices = {
            'FHMM': {
                'model': 'FHMM',
                'sample_period': resample_seconds,
                'max_sample_period': resample_seconds,
                'measurements': [{
                    'physical_quantity': measurement[0],
                    'type': measurement[1]
                }]
            },
            'mains': {
                'model': 'mains',
                'sample_period': resample_seconds,
                'max_sample_period': resample_seconds,
                'measurements': [{
                    'physical_quantity': measurement[0],
                    'type': measurement[1]
                }]
            }
        }

        merged_timeframes = merge_timeframes(timeframes, gap=resample_seconds)
        total_timeframe = TimeFrame(merged_timeframes[0].start,
                                    merged_timeframes[-1].end)

        dataset_metadata = {'name': output_name, 'date': date_now,
                            'meter_devices': meter_devices,
                            'timeframe': total_timeframe.to_dict()}
        output_datastore.save_metadata('/', dataset_metadata)

        # Building metadata

        # Mains meter:
        elec_meters = {
            1: {
                'device_model': 'mains',
                'site_meter': True,
                'data_location': mains_data_location,
                'preprocessing_applied': {},  # TODO
                'statistics': {
                    'timeframe': total_timeframe.to_dict()
                }
            }
        }

        # TODO: FIX THIS! Ugly hack for now
        # Appliances and submeters:
        appliances = []
        for i, meter in enumerate(self.meters):
            meter_instance = meter.instance()

            for app in meter.appliances:
                appliance = {
                    'meters': [meter_instance],
                    'type': app.identifier.type,
                    'instance': app.identifier.instance
                    # TODO this `instance` will only be correct when the
                    # model is trained on the same house as it is tested on.
                    # https://github.com/nilmtk/nilmtk/issues/194
                }
                appliances.append(appliance)

            elec_meters.update({
                meter_instance: {
                    'device_model': 'FHMM',
                    'submeter_of': 1,
                    'data_location': ('{}/elec/meter{}'
                                      .format(building_path, meter_instance)),
                    'preprocessing_applied': {},  # TODO
                    'statistics': {
                        'timeframe': total_timeframe.to_dict()
                    }
                }
            })

            # Setting the name if it exists
            if meter.name:
                if len(meter.name) > 0:
                    elec_meters[meter_instance]['name'] = meter.name
        building_metadata = {
            'instance': mains.building(),
            'elec_meters': elec_meters,
            'appliances': appliances
        }

        output_datastore.save_metadata(building_path, building_metadata)
```

Comment: You should tell us what code you have written, not just what stack trace you get. Obviously line 1 in your file /home/wenwu/untitled0.py is what we are interested in.

Comment: Thx,and I update the code and the problem